# Iterate though directory to post pictures to via API

Tags: python, foreach, iteration, filepath

I want to run this web call on every for every file in a directory variabilizing the path `"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\279259.jpg\"` into the web call.  I think i can use the `os.path.join` but don't know how ot format any help would be appreciated

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("some.website.com")

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\279259.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"

headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",

    'cache-control': "no-cache",

    }

conn.request("POST", "/api/users/pictures", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved if someone has a more elegant solution would love to see.

```
import os
import http.client

Files={}

path = "path"

for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        Files[file] = os.path.dirname(file)
for file in Files:
    print ((path) + (file))
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("website")

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\""+((path)+(file))+"\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
```